# How to pass a date string into an SQL query using Jinja

Tags: python, sql, t-sql, jinja2

I need to pass in a date '20200303' into an SQL table reading jinja.

the python script is as follows:

```
record_date = '20170303'

sql_data = {'date':record_date}

for file in files_sql:
    with open(file) as file_reader:
        sql_template = file_reader.read()

    sql_template = jinja(sql_template)
    sql_query = sql_template.render(data=sql_data)
    spark.sql(sql_query)
```

the sql query file (query_A.sql) it's reading looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table where date <= {{date}}
```

however this is not working and is returning 0 rows. what am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: fixed key from record_date to date, but still having issues

Comment: Your `sql_data` uses the `date` key, so you'll need to use that key in your template.

Comment: and check the format! is '20170303' a valid format or '2017-03-03' or '2017:03:03' is the good ones?

Comment: replace {{record_date}} by {{date}}

Comment: I tried this but still not working.